How to run code which use torch.ones([1], device=torch.device("cuda")) without GPU?
Goal:

Develop PyTorch model in MacBook Pro M2

Problem:

Some CVPR papers use the "device" parameter and set it to "cuda".

So, if the source code is left unmodified, it always throws an error
Code example
import torch

device = torch.device("cuda")
torch.ones([1], device=device)*2

Output
AssertionError: Torch not compiled with CUDA enabled


Cuda specifically denotes sending data to an Nvidia GPU. You cannot run that code as-is without an Nvidia GPU.
You can update the code to torch.device("cpu") to run the code on CPU, or torch.device("mps") if you are using a MacOS device with a GPU and have installed pytorch with the MPS backend

Is there a way to force the entire code to run on cpu? even if somewhere in the code, there is a code like this torch.ones([1], device=torch.device("cuda"))*2

No. If they hard-code the device name the code will always attempt to use that device. This is why it is considered best practice to define the device as a variable in a single location and reference that variable rather than hard-coding device names.
